# How to make Text (within HTML table) getting clicked with Selenium when there is no id assigned(Tried various solutions)?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

The following is a dummy HTML page source (re-created from a page which is not actually looking like a web page, it's generated from a tool and looks like a document):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<table class="DummyObject" style="line-height: 1.3; width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">

    <tr>
        <td title="" style="word-wrap: break-word; font-weight; bold; text-alin: center; vertical-align: middle; font-family; Calibri; font-size: 10pt; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; padding: 3px; color: rgb(0,0,0);">GO</td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Various solutions tried:

By Handling tables function and get table row, and td get value

```
publi void HandlingTables(){
    String s="";
    WebElement table= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='DummyObject'])[30]"));
    List<WebElement> allRows= table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for(WebElement row: allRows){
        List<WebElement> Cells = row.findElements(By.tagName"td"));

            for(WebElement Cell: Cells){
                Cell.click();
            }
    }
}
```

By Click Functions:

```
@FindBy( locator="xpath....")
public WebElement gobtn;

gobtn.waitForPresent(5000)
gobtn.click()
```

By Using JS click:

```
gobtn.clickjs()
```

By Driver instance:

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("")).click();
driver.findelement(By.linktext("GO")).click();
```

By using Actions class:

```
Actions ob=new Actions(driver) 
ob.moveToElement(gobtn).perform()
ob.click(gobtn).perform()
```

By Sendkeys

```
gobtn.sendkeys(keys.ENTER);
```

**Note:** No errors thrown at the console, it's shown in the console that the action is performed, but in the UI it's not getting reflected and the resulting action is not performed.

Please let me know where I did wrong or if there's an alternate way to perform a click operation?

Comment: How can you click on a non-clickable element?

Comment: In the actual page, I'm able to click on it manually, when I checked the element via xpath, the above code snippet is what I could see.

Comment: Then you might have shared the wrong HTML .

Comment: I've created a html file with the provided html code by you, and I can't perform click on it manually.

Comment: The "Go" text, I found only in two places, similar html snippet is there in both places. Is there any other way ti check?

Comment: Is this in an IFRAME?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to click on a non-clickable element ?

You can click on a WebElement if and only if it is clickable. E.g Anchor tags, buttons etc.

**Your code:**

```
driver.findelement(By.linktext("GO")).click();
```

Wouldn't work, if "GO" isn't in a link, basically between `<a> and </a>`

First identify the elements which are clickable, then try to perform click on it.

Comment: I'm able to click on the page manually and the resulting actions are being performed. Also, the page doesn't look like web page, it looks like an excel sheet.

Comment: it is opening in browser ? Does it have URL ?

Comment: It's an internal web page where I'm trying to perform automation testing.

Comment: What does internal web Page means ?

Comment: It cannot be accessed outside.

Comment: then share the HTML where ever you have found two "GO" text?

Comment: It's in the question details. Could you please look into the HTML body

Comment: Yes I could see "GO" text in only one place that is <td> , which can't be clickable at any circumstances

Comment: In both places, where I could see "Go" text, the html snippet looks the same as above. But I'm able to click on it manually and see the resulting action. Could you please suggest a way to debug better?

Comment: search for //a or //button in that particular page , and check how many elements are present ?

Comment: There are no such elements!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168994/discussion-between-sbk-and-cruisepandey).